# Make this part of PHP code faster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a portion of code that isn't so optimized.

Probably a LEFT JOIN will make it faster. But I have some troubles with this kind of advanced queries.

I would like to use the LEFT JOIN with NULL value (http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) for queries into the first cicle.

This is the portion of code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM SitiWeb_Categorie WHERE MaxArticoliConLinks > 0";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Disponibile = 0;
    //Trovo tutti gli articoli redatti ed assegnati a questa categoria
    //Verifico inoltre che non è presente nella tabella delle pubblicazioni
    $query2 = "SELECT Articolisti_Articoli.ID AS ArticoloID FROM Articolisti_Articoli, Articolisti_Incarichi WHERE Articolisti_Incarichi.CategoriaID = '$row[ID]' AND Articolisti_Articoli.IncaricoID = Articolisti_Incarichi.ID ORDER BY Articolisti_Articoli.ID DESC";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $db);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $query3 = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Tot FROM SitiWeb_Articoli WHERE ArticoloID = $row2[ArticoloID]";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $db);
        $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
        if($row3[Tot]==0)
        {
            $Disponibile++;
        }
        if($Disponibile==10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if($Disponibile<10)
    {

    }                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have related tables `SitiWeb_Categorie` and `Articolisti_Articoli`, you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    SitiWeb_Categorie.*,
    Articolisti_Articoli.ID
FROM 
    SitiWeb_Categorie
LEFT JOIN
    Articolisti_Articoli
ON
    Articolisti_Incarichi.CategoriaID=SitiWeb_Categorie.ID
INNER JOIN
    Articolisti_Incarichi
ON
    Articolisti_Articoli.IncaricoID = Articolisti_Incarichi.ID
WHERE
    SitiWeb_Categorie.MaxArticoliConLinks > 0
ORDER BY
    Articolisti_Articoli.ID DESC
```